# SpringBoot 2.6.7 Upgrade Throws Startup Error - Provider for javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory cannot be found

Tags: spring-boot

I am unable to get past this error after upgrading SpringBoot from 2.5.10 - 2.6.7

I did find a version diff in jackson-dataformat-xml and raised an issue but they are confident there is no diff in jackson-dataformat-xml versions https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/521

Anyone faced this issue? Would appreciate if anyone could help

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:2.6.7]
    
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar!/:2.6.7]
    
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'formContentFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedFormContentFilter]: Factory method 'formContentFilter' threw exception; nested exception is javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory cannot be found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedFormContentFilter]: Factory method 'formContentFilter' threw exception; nested exception is javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory cannot be found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory cannot be found
    at javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.find(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory.newFactory(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory.<init>(XmlFactory.java:124) ~[jackson-dataformat-xml-2.13.2.jar!/:2.13.2]
```

Comment: Have you checked that Woodstox is on the classpath and that its jar file has not be corrupted?